# I can't seem to make .indexOf() work for my char array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, arduino, char

I need to get a string from my second array (morsecode) but I need to know the index of the letter I can get from my first array (morse).

These are my arrays:

```
char morse[27]={' ','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
String morsecode[27]={",",".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."};
String words[] = "my message";
```

And this is me trying to access the array and get the index of the char (these blocks of codes are looped):

```
counter=0;
char letter = words[counter];
letter = toLowerCase(letter);
int location=morse.indexOf(letter);
String code=morsecode[location];
counter++;
```

Every time I try to compile this error comes out:

> exit status 1
>   request for member 'indexOf' in 'morse', which is of non-class type 'char [27]'

Comment: `morse` is a `char` array, it doesn't have any members.

Comment: Perhaps you should make `morse` a *`String`* instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i changed the morse and letter to String. Now i get this error insted:
exit status 1
`request for member 'indexOf' in 'morse', which is of non-class type 'String [27]'`

Comment: Make it `String`, not `String [27]`.

Comment: `String morse = " abc..."`

Comment: @ArchangelAzrael That's the point. You don't need it to be an array.

Comment: That worked... thank you guys. one last question. why didnt the array work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

morse is an array of char. indexOf is a string (class) method.

You could try this:

```
String char_to_morse(char letter)
{
    String morsecode[]={".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."};

    if ((letter >= 'a') && (letter <= 'z')) return morsecode[a - 'a'];
    else if ((letter >= 'A') && (letter <= 'Z')) return morsecode[a - 'A'];
    else if (letter == ' ') return "     "; // longer space to see different words
    else return "ERR";
}

main() {
    String words[] = "my message";

    int i=0;
    String result;
    while (words[i])
    {
        result += char_to_morse(words[i]) + ' '; // use space to separate each morse code.
    }

    printf(result);
}
```

The morsecode[a - 'a']; is a quick way to return the position of the ASCII char. a=0, b=1, etc...

Bonus, this is case insensitive